# Can I clone an existing OSMC installation onto a separate card that runs Berryboot?

Tags: backup, osmc, berryboot

So I have a Raspberry Pi 3B that I have setup to run OSMC. I would like to use the same Pi, but be able to boot from a choice of systems.

[Berryboot](https://www.berryterminal.com/doku.php/berryboot) seems like a perfect solution, but is there a way to clone my existing system as an option to boot? I don't want to lose my configuration for the OSMC I already run if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Berryboot has a number of limitations. I haven't used it for years but all OS must share a common kernel.

I suggest you look at [PINN](https://github.com/procount/pinn/blob/master/README_PINN.md) which is well documented, including building custom OS - all of which operate independently.

Personally, I wouldn't bother - it is just as easy to swap SD Cards.

Comment: I haven't heard of PINN, but I will check it out. So if I have a backup `.img` of my osmc sd card, would I be able to use that as one of the OS's? The placement of my RPi in my media console makes it a bit annoying to swap cards, so something that can let me choose what to boot would be perfect for me.

Comment: @lukehod The actual OS is just 2 normal partitions - you would need to adjust PARTUUID in cmdline.txt and /etc/fstab and prepare a file for PINN. The easiest would be to do a fresh install of OSMC and overwrite to root partition. PINN has extensive documentation.